# Script Validation in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a bunch of insert...select statements like the below format in a script file.

```
insert into 
tablename
(
col1,
col2,
...
...
coln
)
select
col1,
col2,
...
coln
from 
table2
```

My file contains around 3000 insert...select statements. I want to validate the script based on the following.

1. The number of columns mentioned in the insert and select statements should be same
2. Column names in the insert and select should match.

I am scanning the insert scripts manually but this is a time consuming tasks and I don't know when I will complete.

Please suggest any ideas to do this process in an efficient manner.

Comment: I would use Python or some similar language to parse and validate it; should be easy enough.

Comment: There is no syntax errors in this file, but there are lot of mismatched columns like (insert into tablename (col1,col2) select col4,col2 from tablename. In this statement col4 is mapped with col1 in insert. I have to identify those scripts.

Comment: might be this will help you `MERGE INTO [dbo].[UserUserRole] AS Target
USING (VALUES

    (1, 1)

) AS Source ([UserID], [RoleID])
ON Target.[UserID] = Source.[UserID] AND Target.[RoleID] = Source.[RoleID]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
-- Insert new rows
INSERT ([UserID], [RoleID])
VALUES ([UserID], [RoleID]);`

Comment: tinka is right, you can merge it

Comment: Give me a sample example for this since I am not able to follow this logic

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS you can look at the estimated query plan. If something is incorrect, it will show up.

You can also set NOEXEC to on at the begining of your script.

> Compiles each query but does not execute it. [MSDN: SET NOEXEC (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188394.aspx)

```
SET NOEXEC ON
```

Comment: I have to identify the mismatched columns in the script but this will check for syntax errors

Comment: There is no syntax errors in this file, but there are lot of mismatched columns like (insert into tablename (col1,col2) select col4,col2 from tablename). In this statement col4 is mapped with col1 in insert. I have to identify those scripts

Comment: It will at least tell you if the number of columns if different => 1. The number of columns mentioned in the insert and select statements should be same

Comment: Sorry I can't get you. Could you please tell me briefly

Comment: You said that the number of column in the insert and select statement should be the same. if they are not the same, you will have an error: The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list

Comment: This addresses part 1 of the question but not part 2. To check that the column names match, you could use regular expressions via any number of scripting languages (powershell, python, etc). If the scripts are simple inserts that wouldn't be too hard to do.